# How to initialize an array store in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I tried initializing an array which I would like accessible from different modules.

```
export const columns = readable(['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body']);
```

I can successfully loop through that store in html sections like this.

```
{#each $columns as col}
```

However I am not able to loop through the values in script sections. How can the values be accessed? Was this the wrong way to initialize the shared array? Is there a better way to set up a shared array that's accessible from anywhere and doesn't change?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to access a value (& subsequently their children) from a `svelte` store depending on the context where your script is run:

1. In a `.svelte` file
2. Outside a `.svelte` file (eg. a `.js` or `.ts` file)

> Side note: As Stephane Vanraes pointed out in their answer, it is advisable to use `Object.freeze` if you aren't modifying the contents of your array anywhere else, as putting it in your `readable` will only prevent the reference from changing & not its contents.

## 1. In a `.svelte` file

Here, you may prepend `$` to the front of store variables to access their values (& subsequently their children):

```html
<script>
  import { readable } from 'svelte/store';
  const columns = readable(
    Object.freeze(
      ['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body'],
    ),
  );

  console.log($columns); //  ['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body']
  console.log($columns[0]);  // 'id'
</script>
```

## 2. Outside a `.svelte` file

Here, you may use the exported `get` method from `svelte/store`:

```js
import { get, readable } from 'svelte/store';
const columns = readable(
  Object.freeze(
    ['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body'],
  ),
);

console.log(get(columns)); // ['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body']
console.log(get(columns[0])); // 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the script section of a Svelte component you can simply use `$columns.forEach(...)` to loop over your array.

That said, if this array *never ever* changes and is fixed in the code itself (as in: you already know the values beforehand) you do not need the (minimal) overhead of a store but you can simply do

```js
export const columns = ['id', 'postId', 'name', 'email', 'body'];
Object.freeze(columns);
```

The `freeze` prevents the array from ever changing.